# Adjusting Legend Shiny R

Tags: r, shiny, legend

I am trying to get rid of the blank white gap as shown below, but can't seem to figure out exactly how to do it.

[image]

Sample code:

```
 legend("bottom", 
         colnames(bvoip.collab.seats)[3:4],
         xpd = FALSE,
         horiz = TRUE, 
         #ncol = 1 , 
         inset = c(0, 0),
         bty = "o",
         bg = "gray90", 
         box.col="gray90",
         pch = c(15, 15, 15, 15, 15), 
         col = c(attDarkBlue,attOrange,attGreen), 
         legend = c(" Collaborate-Enhanced Mobile"," Collaborate"," Collaborate-Internal"),
         pt.cex = 1.3,cex = 0.8,yjust = 0.5)
```

Comment: You could try to adjust `text.width` and/or `x.intersp`?

Comment: Would you also accept a `ggplot2` answer? If not, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45956950/3682794) might be interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a work around, but using "text.width" property in Legend() got the job done. It is not perfect, but it will do.

```
text.width=c(.5,.2,.5),
```

Whole Code

```
legend("bottom", 
         colnames(bvoip.collab.seats)[3:4],
         xpd = FALSE,
         horiz = TRUE, 
         text.width=c(.5,.2,.5),
         #ncol = 1 , 
         inset = c(0, 0),
         bty = "o",
         bg = "gray90", 
         box.col="gray90",
         pch = c(15, 15, 15, 15, 15), 
         col = c(attDarkBlue,attOrange,attGreen), 
         legend = c(" Collaborate-Enhanced Mobile", " Collaborate", " Collaborate-Internal"),
         pt.cex = 1.3,cex = 0.8,yjust = 0.5)
```

[image]