# Is there a way to reduce the spacing between legend columns [Base R]?

Tags: r, plot, legend

I'm creating a figure in base R (not my preference, but that's what I've been told to do), and I'm having trouble with the spacing of the columns in the legend. When the plot is zoomed in the gap between the columns is larger than I would like, especially when there will be a lot more keys in the figure than what I've written here. Is there a parameter that controls that or a way to work around it?
[image: Example Figure]

```
plot(1, 1)
legend("bottomleft",
       legend = c("Study 1: Additional Text", 
                  "Study 2: Additional Text",
                  "Study 3: Additional Text",
                  "Study 4: Additional Text"),
       pch = 16:19,
       lty = 1:4,
       bty = "n",
       col = c("black", "red", "blue", "brown"),
       ncol = 2)
```

Comment: I don't think there is a parameter that will do what you want.  I ran your code in RStudio and it looked fine in the plot window, but when I zoomed it looked as yours does above.  I would recommend saving the plot directly to a image file or pdf/ps and then you can open and zoom without it being a problem .

Comment: Have you seen [Adjust spacing between text in horizontal legend](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21262472/4752675)